# Is it a good idea to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in includes?

Tags: php

Is this, for example, a good idea?

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include.php');
```

If you have two virtual hosts on the same server, one for live and one for development, with different Apache DocumentRoots, this would avoid having to include absolute paths when the source of the include is unknown, and may be in any directory.

(Note: file paths in the following section are relative to the web root. They would in fact be like `/var/www/app/core/init.php`, where `/var/www/app` is the web root)

For instance: I have an /core/init.php which is called using relative paths from places all over the website (`/file.php`, `/dir/file.php or /dir/dir/file.php`).

This init.php then includes several function pages, in the fund directory, a subdir of `/core` (as in `/core/func/userfunctions.php`).

So, in init.php, I can use the `$_SERVER` method, because it breaks if I use a relative path and try to call functions from a page like `/dir/file.php`.

I can't see any problem with it, but in general what could go wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've seen cases where `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not set or is not what you would expect (i.e. not set in CLI or old IIS, or invalid in certain CGI setups).

For that reason you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to obtain the path of the script that line is called in.  You can then reference relative paths from there e.g.

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../other/file.php';
```

I go with the above method when the directory structure of the files is known and is not subject to change.

If `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is not available, the following is a suitable replacement:

```
substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

Comment: that didn't work for me. I simply used: include  `'..\wp-load.php';`  cause I had my project on the same directory as wp-includes, wp-content, ap-admin...

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales `include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../other/file.php';` is the right way to do it. That's because PHP looks for current working directory (cwd) and then you append `'..\wp-load.php';`, this may not always work as you expect. Read more about getcwd in here: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this. PHP looks for the included file in the document root by default.

You can use [set_include_path($new_include_path)](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to change this behaviour, or edit  [include_path](http://es.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in the php config file.

Also, from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php:

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
>       The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Comment: I'm not sure I explained myself fully. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you use URL rewriting, you will be very happy when you find out that the includes in your `/there/are/so/many/paths/in/the/url/of/this/` page are still working!