# PHP document root in includes

Tags: php

At the moment I have this on every page of my site so I can use the same site code on a dev site on the same server but it seems maybe their is a better way than this?

```
define("DOC_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$folder=explode("/",DOC_ROOT);

include("/home/".$folder[2]."/header.php");
```

Comment: Maybe some interesting advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893832/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-serverdocument-root-in-includes?rq=1

Comment: in php.ini there is [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [auto_append_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a common file for all such general things (database connection initiation, common object creations, determining language, holding database usernames and passwords etc), I call it `master_config.php`.

looks something like:

```
define("SITE","www.example.com");
define("DB_SERV", "db.com");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");
define("GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY", "qweasd");
$db = new database();
$db -> connect(DB_SERV,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
.. etc
```

So if You create a new page, then you just include the `master_config.php` to it and all common objects, variables and settings are already brought to the page. You can add your folder setting and exploding to the same common file and just use portions that You need in respective php files.