# Standalone pages in theme folder in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wish to create a standalone page inside my theme folder, Is it possible. I have tried with the following code,

```
<?php 
require_once('wp-load.php');
?>
```

this works fine when the my standalone page - 'custom.php' is inside root of the site and the above code on top of my custom.php page, but when I move the file to my theme folder, it shows page not found error. I have changed the wp-load.php file location to this--

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
```

Is it possible to do this, Or if i am doing the wrong way, please help, thanx in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Is it a good idea to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'\] in includes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11893832/367456)

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Honestly, don't. You do *not* want to be worrying about your theme's folder when doing this kind of stuff.

Create a page template, with whatever code, presentation or logic you want in it, and assign the template to a static page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

If you need form handlers and so forth, there are many hooks in WP that let take care of them.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks

Answer (score 0):

you can do it very easy,

- add a folder beside your wp-content, wp-admin and wp-includes
- put inside your index.php
- call it like this e.g: http://your-site/yourNewFolder