# php root path assigned to variable

Tags: php

I'm a bit mixed up about php path's. I have a `global.php` file to assign the root path to a variable so that I can change locally instead of in every file. It looks like this:

```
$domain_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Apparently this gives me a url and `include()` doesn't like it ( `http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0` ).

This `global.php` file is in the website "root/common" and gets included by all files in different directories.

This works if I write in every file:
`<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/common/head_info_'.AC_LANG.'.php'; ?>`

but this doesn't (and I know global.php was included):
`<?php include $domain_path.'/common/head_info_'.AC_LANG.'.php'; ?>`.

**Q:** How can I assign a path to that variable so it works inside each different file?

Comment: Scope Problem, make sure that variable is in same scope as the statement which needsit

Comment: For what you're trying to do, I think it might be easier to use the predefined define [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: @TomasCreemers, if I have `$domain_path= __DIR__;` I get also the same echo `/www/webvol15/3x/ihxfrbqzhhhhknxdp/[etc]` and the error described above.

Comment: @Rikard: I understand. My comment was not supposed to be an answer but a general remark. The reason why I suggested `__DIR__` is because it is more universal (as long as you stay above PHP 5.3). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11894051/2662457

Comment: @TomasCreemers, ok. Thank you for the suggestion and the link. I think you have agood point and I will study it so I feel I understand it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem, is your global variable in same scope?

You can do

```
$_GLOBALS["domain_path"] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

and use it like

```
<?php include $_GLOBALS["domain_path"].'/common/head_info_'.AC_LANG.'.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for checking this. I have no global variables I just include the global.php file and I can echo the `$domain_path` inside the file, just I get a url like `/www/webvol15/3x/ihxfrbqzhhhhknxdp/[etc...]`

Comment: @Rikard: that is actually not a URL but a local filesystem path.

Comment: @TomasCreemers, yes, but `include()` complains about it, the error is in the question post.

Comment: Yep! that did it. +1 to you and I will have some reading to do. Thank you.

Comment: @Rikard: which is why I didn't post it as an answer but as a comment :-) That path looks like a normal way a hoster would divide the file system. Perhaps finding out where the 'http://' comes from where the `include` complains about is worth looking into?