# How to properly use $_SERVER

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this code to generate the images that I am supposed to upload images.

I used this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/trainee/Desktop/tmp/';
```

where the uploaded images will go to **/home/trainee/Desktop/tmp/**

Did I use the proper arguement with this code? Please help :(

Comment: I would suggest you to refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893832/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-serverdocument-root-in-includes

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is the root directory of your web site, so if the web site is at `/var/www`, you'll be writing the files to `/var/www/home/trainee/Desktop/tmp/`. If you just want an absolute path (ie not relative to the web site directory), just use the path without `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: Is this applicable when I want the images to appear on my browser? I am using Ubunutu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Please provide more code and be clear.

That .../tmp/ is location where you'll save images for uploading to online server, or that is location on server from where you wish to include images to your HTML pages?

Online youll have access to /home/user/public_html/... Instead ...Desktop/

Comment: I got the wrong idea, the question is this. Do I need to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for displaying the image that I submitted from a form. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT] contains the ABSOLUTE path to your webserver's document directory. Absolute means it starts from the root-folder of the computer.

I sugguest you display the whole path-string this way:

```
echo '<p>' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/home/trainee/Desktop/tmp/</p>';
```

Then check if the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Do I need to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for displaying the image that I submitted from a form. Sorry for the inconvenience."

It is one possibility. You don't need to use this way but you can.
But you can also work with a relative path. Relative to the script which is responsible for displaying the images.
Have a look at this: 
http://bitflop.com/document/95