# Creating absolute path in PHP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I've created a PHP file **url.php** and wrote this codes -

```
<?php
define("BASE_URL", "/geo15/" );
define("ROOT_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "geo15/" );
?>
```

I've included the **url.php** file in several pages but when I browse those files, I get this error message:

> Warning: require_once(inc/url.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\wamp\www\geo15\inc\header.php on line 1

But when I paste the path *C:\wamp\www\geo15\inc\header.php* in my browser's URL bar, it opens.

N.B. I'm using WAMP server for the development.

Comment: do u mean define("BASE_URL", ".../geo15/" );

Comment: No, the constant BASE_URL is working perfectly, but ROOT_PATH isn't working. I want to create an absolute path to my header.php file.

Comment: This might solve your problem -->    [http://stackoverflow.com/q/11893832/3949439][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11893832/3949439

Comment: @Utkarsh Vishnoi I went through the links you've provided but could not get it.
This is my present code in **url.php** file
`<?php

define("BASE_URL", "/geo15/" );
define("ROOT_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "geo15/" );

?>`

So what it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOCUMENT_ROOT would output something like "c:/wamp/www" so you'll be missing one / there. Your current code would actually output something like "c:/wamp/wwwgeo15/".

Also, make sure that 'geo15/' is in the actual www directory rather than an alias. If it is an alias then you'll definitely get a broken link. In addition, you might find the following useful:

dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])

- Would output something like 'x:/path/to/the/current/executing/php/file'.
- $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] would output something like 'x:/path/to/the/current/executing/php/file/theCurrentRunningFile.php'.
- This is useful for locating pages that you need to include, includeonce, or require.

dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

- Would output something like '/myAliasDirectory/and/path/to/current/php/file'.
- $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] would output something like '/myAliasDirectory/and/path/to/current/php/file/theCurrentRunningFile.php'.
- This is useful for creating dynamic hyperlinks.

Alternatively, if you have a lot of sub-directories, you might want to consider using "../" to point out a directory above the current directory. So, if your script is "/my/path/to/current/runningscript.php" and the file you want to include is in "/include/this/file.php", then the right way to include it is "include('../../../../../include/this/file.php');".

And.. beginning with a "/" will also bring you to the root directory or actually, it can either point to the root directory of the current alias OR the root directory of the hard drive, while beginning with no slash will start on the current directory of the running script. If you're working in an alias "/myAliasDirectory/" starting your include with / like in "include('/file.php')" would work if "file.php" is in either "x:/file.php" or "/myAliasDirectory/file.php". So yeah, it gets pretty confusing if you do that so I'll only half recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code (in Unix):

```
 include dirname(__FILE__).'/paht/relative/to/the/current/file/file_name.php';
```

It works in all situations.

in Windows, you may use:

```
 include dirname(__FILE__).'\paht\relative\to\the\current\file\file_name.php';
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\geo15\pages\bazi-analysis../../inc/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\geo15\pages\bazi-analysis\3-years-bazi-analysis.php on line 1`

Comment: @Crtvca If the server OS is windows, you should use backslash ( ` \ ` ) to separate directories, and if it is Linux(Unix), you use forward-slash ( ` / ` ). apparently you are running in windows, so you should replace forward slash with backward slash.