# PHP upload files to remote server

Tags: php

I am completely a novice in all this ...
I have created a Social Networking project in which there is a module which allows user to upload photos..
I have hosted this project in my college server

I access that server using bitvise client with my server credentials.

My problem is i don't know how to setup upload mechanism for remote server ... In my localhost i simply use

> move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file);

function but i don't know how to do this for remote server ...

I tried FTP by looking at some tutorials but that didn't worked for me.
In my project structure there is a directory

> users/user_id (diff for all users)/photos

here i want to place the uploaded files....
A proper description with example and proper functioning might be very helpful for me.... Thank you

**EDIT:** 
 Below is my code.

#### Photos.php

```
<form class="input-group-btn" method="post" action="editPhotos.php"enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="form-submit">Done</button>
</form>
```

#### editPhotos.php

```
if( isset($_POST['form-submit']) ){
    $target_file = "users/".$email."/pictures/Photos/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
    $img =str_replace(" ", "",basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    rename($target_file, "users/".$email."/pictures/Photos/".$img);
    header('Refresh: 1; url=Photos.php?user='.$email);
}
```

Comment: there is no different code for local and server . same way you can upload to server

Comment: i have added the code please tell me where i went wrong...

Comment: Most of the commands in your code do return a value. You need to check the return value and handle the case if the command failed (error case). You can't just assume that there is only the good outcome (happy path), but there can also be failures. This is important on the file-system as it tends to fail (at least occasionally). This is also important because when you ask a question regarding code you should point to the place of the code that differs to your expectation. E.g. what did you expect to happen, what happened instead? That will progress towards an answer much faster.

Comment: try to add absolute path $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."users/".$email."/pictures/Photos/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: $target_file =dirname(__FILE__)."users/".$email."/pictures/Photos/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: i am getting the file name on the server?  does that means the file transfer to the server is successful? if yes then why isn't the file getting copied to the path which i specified

Comment: did you getting any error ?  your folder have read and write permission  ?

Comment: @SagarKhan: To check whether the transfer is successfull needs to be done in your code first. We can't say. You can't say. But you can, if you add the checks: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php, see especially the error messages explained part.

Comment: @JYoThI yes i have read write permissions on the server directory....

Comment: @hakre i have applied the checks for the successful uploads, the upload is failed...
One question i want to ask is how will the file get transferred from local computer to remote server?

Comment: @JYoThI: This is a more correct link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11893832/367456 - I had the wrong one reg. DOCUMENT_ROOT, the background is similar though. Some values are just not trustworthy.

Comment: @SagarKhan: The browser sends the file to the server when the form is submitted. That is with the HTTP POST request. PHP then processes the form POST data and offers an interface (e.g. `$_FILES` array, the upload functions) to process the data as files.

Comment: @SagarKhan: Check the PHP error log on the server, it should give more infos what went wrong. Can be just some configuration setting or incorrect access rights of a folder or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Small tutorial how to upload file.

For sure, you need correct `encryption` and file's type in your `form` (ommited other fields, to clear example):

#### form.html

```
< form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">< /form>
< input name="test" type=file>
```

#### upload.php

In `$_FILES` you have all data of uploaded file. In given example, we have field named `test`.

Advice, to always first check error `$_FILES['test']['error']` - the values you can find in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

If this is correct, then prepare upload path. Some advices:

- remember that if you use original filename (`$_FILES['test']['name']`), then is User upload second file, with same name, you will need overwrite file or ignore upload. Other way, is to save data to database and generate temporary name form him.
- destination path(target_file) - regardless if upload folder is in the same catalog, you should always use global path, as good practice. You can use [**DIR**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for that.
- don't use in path data, like email - is you have project, and want give opportunity to change email in configuration, what you will do with files? Better save user to Database and use his ID as key.

If you have path, then you simply need only use of [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), but remember to check result, as it not always will return true. You can have error, when you don't have permissions to destination folder (you'll need debug this).

I see that you, first upload file, then rename (then you should check, if rename was success). Don't extends this process, if it not necessary. Upload file for final path and name.

#### Example of code (I this rattle off)

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $fileName = str_replace(" ", "", $fileName);

    $target_file = sprintf(__DIR__ . "/users/%s/pictures/Photos/%s", $email, $fileName);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        // File was uploaded
        header('Refresh: 1; url=Photos.php?user=' . $email);

    } else {
        // File was not uploaded;
        throw new \Exception('File was not uploaded. Check warnings.');
    }
}
```

- Used other method to check, if this is `POST`
- use method [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), for better code quality
- checked effect of `move_uploaded_file`
- use global path for destination file

Comment: one question i was just checking my read write permissions on the server the directory is something like this
/var/www/html/sagar/social
social is my project
Now i have read write permissions only for these -> html/sagar/social folder and not for var/www (i just have read permissions for this) does this affect the upload?

Comment: Should not. This means you can't change anything in upper part of tree folder, but you have good permissions to your own. Remember, that PHP script are run by Apache/nginx with others user - he usually have same right for all subfolders of `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score -1):

---

> **Below code is risky in live environment, please use cautiously**

---

Use a relative path to the uploads folder. For example, if your **uploads** folder is placed outside your current folder. Then

```
$PATH = '/absolute/example/path/to/uploads';//from config file    
$target_file = "$PATH/file_name";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
```

The above code will work both in local and remote server.

Other checks are below:

1. Check for [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) while uploading file in server

To enable error handling use below code in your upload logic:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

2. Another important note is to make **uploads** folder [writable](https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux) otherwise file upload wont work.

Comment: Very bad idea, you perhaps meant to use a configuration setting. The base path (you make use of with your relative path implicitly) is undefined in your scenario and depends on a lot of state that line of code will executed in. This is pretty risky (e.g. what happens if cwd is not what you expect) ...

Comment: i have updated the question also added the code... i yes my upload folder is in the same directory

Comment: so absolute path means should i pass this path?
/var/www/html/sagar/social/users......? Still not working

Comment: @SagarKhan yes, you can also use [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant :) this is path to folder where you executed PHP file is.

Comment: @SagarKhan: The answer given is a guess (done in good faith) what could be  a solution to your (quite unspecified) problem question. I was pointing out an issue with using relative paths (which you have as well in the original code) but that must not be the blocker you're currently experiencing (but still correct to do instead). Crazy, right? Technically there is a lot of information to process to come to the good outcome, but we need to write in sharing the info on this website and this is quite hard and crazy with broad questions.

Comment: The documentation on file uploads is very well on the PHP website: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php - It's a bit to read but the topic needs a bit of reading so that is fine.